# Connecting to MySQL using Apache and PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database, apache, connection

i'm currently on Apache 2.2 using PHP 5..
I am trying to connect to to MySQL on my Apache server and  create a database called my_db...
and i have the following code:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect();
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}else{
echo "Connected Successfully!";
}
// Create database
$sql="CREATE DATABASE my_db";
if (mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
echo "Database my_db created successfully";
}else{
echo "Error creating database: " . mysqli_error();
}
?>
```

However, when the script runs i get the following output:

> Connected Successfully!Error creating database:

Please help. It is not an authentication problem since "Connected Successfully!" is printed...

Thankyou in advance!

Comment: maybe you haven't permission to create database on default user

Comment: I would suspect that the mysql user you are logging in with does not have CREATE rights. A mysql user can have one or a group of many different permissions. |Do you know if you have phpmyadmin? :http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php PHPmyadmin will allow you to administer mysql a lot easier.  If you dont already have it, consider having it installed or using a tool such as Navicat.

Comment: To create and delete a database one should have admin privilege. Check it out

Answer (score 1):

You can query an overview of the user privileges by using:

```
SHOW GRANTS FOR 'user'@'host';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a new user on the mysql command line, grant this user all privileges, and then connect as this new user and try to create the database. This should solve your problem. Assuming you're connecting to mysql on localhost the code you need to create the new user is:

```
bash# mysql --user=root -p

mysql> CREATE USER 'monty'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'some_pass';
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'monty'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace 
`echo "Error creating database: " . mysqli_error();`
with
`echo "Error creating database: " . mysqli_error($con);`

Add `$con` as an argument in `mysqli_error` function,
And you will get exact error,

http://php.net/mysqli_error